# nginx/openresty - how to implement server_names in valid_referers?

Tags: nginx, lua, environment-variables, openresty

I'm using the [OpenResty Web platform](https://openresty.org/)
to make my nginx config fully customizable trough environment variables. This seems to work pretty fine for the server_name option, as shown below.

But if I set `servers_names` at the `valid_referers` option it seems that nginx is not able to understand the `server_names` (as it in general referees to `server_name`) option anymore or maybe im doing something wrong here.
I just want that `server_name` is understood by nginx so that it can be used at `valid_referers`

my .env file:

```
NGINX_SERVERNAMES=localhost
```

nginx.conf

```
env NGINX_SERVERNAMES;
...
server {
        set_by_lua $curr_server_name 'return os.getenv("NGINX_SERVERNAMES")';
        server_name $curr_server_name;
        valid_referers none blocked server_names;
```

results in ->

> conflicting parameter
>   "$curr_server_name" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:185

thanks for reading

Comment: You're not using the `$current_server_names` variable anywhere though 

Comment: even if i do valid_referers none blocked server_names $curr_server_name; or valid_referers none blocked $curr_server_name;
It does not work

Comment: "does not work" how? what do you expect to happen? what actually happens? Either ask a specific question, or provide something that can easily be reproduced, otherwise it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Comment: What I expect is that the server_names are getting recognized by valid_referers as it usualy does with nginx. "server_names" of valid_referers quals server_name $curr_server_name; as my domains are the only valid referers here ...

Comment: Where are you using `$current_server_names` though? And where do you set `$curr_server_name`?

Comment: Copy paste mistake, corrected